# htmlentities and htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm having a really hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong with `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars`

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

This is the input:

```
test % test $ test & test " test ' test ;
```

In the browser output, the `&` and `'` and `"` are displaying as their entities instead of as the characters themselves. What step is missing to get these to display normally instead of as encoded entities?

Comment: It looks like you're double-encoding them...

Comment: What exactly do you expect and what does it return to you?

Comment: I'm expecting to input that string, save it in the db, and when I use htmlspecialchars on output to the page, to see that string as it was input. Instead, I'm getting the encoded entity being display such as &#3.. etc

Niet, I don't see anywhere where I could be double-encoding, but I'll check again

Comment: I think you might be right Niet, I take away the present encoding and see some characters are encoded. I'm still not sure where, but that appears to be right. Thanks.